# Route Inspection / Chinese Postman Problem via TSP

Tags: graph, path

I'm trying to solve a Route Inspection / Chinese Postman Problem via TSP, by solving the line graph L(G) of the route graph G.

1. Graph G is described by a list of lines with start/end point coordinates.
2. Line graph L(G) described as a list of center points of lines.
3. Solve L(G) via TSP.
4. Calculate the order of lines in G from #3.

As you can see in the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nba9Q.png), there are multiple equally expensive solutions for L(G). However, when converting the solution back to G, some of these solutions create overlapping lines/jumps, that add to the cost.

How can I make sure I always find the cheapest solution of G, when solving for L(G)? Is there a mistake in my logic/execution?

Answer (score 0):

If your graph has at most 2 nodes with odd degree, say s and t, like in your example, then you certainly want the postman tour to start in s and end at t (or vice versa). In this case, a Eulerian path exists which traverses every edge exactly once, which of course must be a minimum Chinese postman tour. So you can use any algorithm to construct a Eulerian path from s to t and that will be an optimal solution.

When many more nodes have odd degree, I am not sure if the approach using the line graph is correct. But let me observe that using a TSP algorithm to solve the Chinese Postman problem is a bit like trying to hit a mosquito with a cannon: TSP is NP-hard, while the Chinese Postman is known to admit polynomial time algorithms.